# iOS7 image added programmatically is blurred

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview

This how I add an image:

```
UIImageView *imageHolder = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
    CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (290/2),(self.view.frame.size.height) - (140 * 1.8), 290, 140)];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-pins.png"];
imageHolder.image = image;
imageHolder.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
// optional:
// [imageHolder sizeToFit];
[self.view addSubview:imageHolder];
```

The size of the image (retina version) is exactly the same size as in CGRectMake above. However the image is a little blurred. I only can reduce the blur when I edit the image and give it a higher resolution in photoshop.

But images that I add through storyboard are all fine in quality. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: What is the frame of the image view (and all of its superviews)? What is the pixel size of the image (290x140 or 580x280)?

Comment: Pixel size is 290x140 (@2x). What do you mean by frame, not familiar with that..

Comment: "frame" as in, the word that you put three times into your code. The CGRect that describes where and how big the view is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retina graphics, the image size should be twice the size of the `frame` of the image view. This allows the image to use a `scale` of 2 to take advantage of the retina screen capability. So, you should have one image of size 290x140 (if you are supporting non-retina devices) and one image of size 580x280 (this is the `@2x` image).

The [`frame`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#jumpTo_14) of the view is the description of the position and size of the view within the view hierarchy (in terms of the superview coordinate system). If you have fractional values in the `frame` size or position you can get 'blurring' effects.